# Can i use two delegates: delegateA in classB, delegateB in classA?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

i've got my code in HelloWorldLayer, i'm using a delegate to change the score number in ScoreLayer, and i would like **to send a message back** from ScoreLayer to HelloWorldLayer, in order to change the ui with a new image.

Is it ok to create a delegate in each class (one delegate of HelloW... in ScoreLayer, and one delegate of ScoreLayer in HelloW...) ? Something like that :

```
hellolayer.delegate = scoreLayer;
scoreLayer.powerUpDelegate = hellolayer;
```

?

`@class MyClass` does not work : the protocols are not being recognized.
`"#import "..."` : one of the protocol is not recognized, but i guess there will be a problem, as classA will import classB, which will import classA again etc.

How should i do? Here's some of the code :

```
    //in HelloWorldLayer.h :

#import "ScoreLayer.h"

@protocol PowerUpDelegate
-(void)scalePowerUp;
@end


// HelloWorldLayer
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <PowerUpDelegate>
{ … }

@property (nonatomic,retain) id <ScoreDelegate> delegate;




//in ScoreLayer.h :

//@class HelloWorldLayer; -->does not recognize the protocol
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

@protocol ScoreDelegate
//...
@end

@interface ScoreLayer : CCLayer <ScoreDelegate>{
    //...
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) id <PowerUpDelegate> powerUpDelegate;//-->cannot find protocol definition...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a third class which implements both protocols and use that class to handle the delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you can pre-declare the protocols like you pre-declare classes, so put this at the top of your `ScoreLayer` class:

```
@protocol PowerUpDelegate;
```

Comment: thanks! i didn't know that, well i created a 3d class and it works fine, thanks for your answer!